# How to create two different sessions for normal users and admin users using express-session?

Tags: node.js, session-cookies, express-session

In my app, two types of users get logged in: normal users and admin users. Right now I am using single session for both type of users and my app is behaving abnormal. When two or more users get logged in, after sometime some user gets logout unexpectedly.

I thought this problem was occurred due to single session and I tried to split into two different sessions as,

```
//manage session for normal user
app.use('/', session({
    key: USER_SESS_NAME, 
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    secret: SESSION_SECRET,
    cookie: {
        expires: 600000
    }
}));


//manage session for admin
app.use('/admin', session({
    key: ADMIN_SESS_NAME, 
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    secret: SESSION_SECRET,
    cookie: {
        expires: 600000
    }
}));
```

Also, all routes for normal user starts with '/' and for admin they starts with '/admin' so I split sessions as above.

I don't know whether it is right way of creating two different sessions. Moreover, the session for admin is also not working as expected. When I get logout as normal user, I also get logged out from admin. What is the best way of handling these sessions and what things we need to do while logging out??

Answer (score 2):

Use a single session for all user types. The best way will be to use account type in session to separate users.

Whenever a user signs up, set the value for normal user and admin user. In your session secret include the account type.

The format should look like:

```
secret: YOUR_SECRET.usertype
```

so that you can split it with the dot and determine the user type. This way you will have a single session with user-type on it.

Comment: Yes, actually I was doing same but the thing happened is as I logged in as user and admin on same window and when I got logged out from admin,  it automatically logout me from normal user too. Isn't it due to same session? If not please can you mention things that I need to do during logout?

Comment: I think you are destroying the session when logging out and it destroys the session with the same keys. It is because of the same session and you should only allow one account at a time to log in. If the user is logged in, he/she should log out to use another account. This is the best way. Multiple logins is not a better option I guess.

Comment: I have set two different types of keys when user and admin login respectively. And when logging out, I have used session.destroy(). Is this the  reason??

Comment: yes, session.destroy will destroy the active session so when two users logs in, both session will be destroyed.

Comment: Allow only one user session at a time. If one has to log in as admin, he/she should log out user account and vice versa.

Comment: >Whenever a user signs up, set the value for normal user and admin user. In your session secret include the account type.

This may fly in development as you're toying around, but whats the most effective way to do this as you move towards getting the app ready for production? Would you set up a route for admins to assign roles, and give everyone the default role of "user" as they sign up?